# Using callback for asynchronous in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I know nowaday it has promise or await async for asynchronous things in javascript. I just trying figure out how callback work and use it for real.
I have something like this

```
// HTML
<input type="file" id="file-to-load" />
<button onClick="handleFile()">SHOW DATA</button>

// JS
function readData(callback) {
  var data;

  var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("file-to-load").files[0];
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
  fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
    data = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
  }

  callback(data);
}

function showData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

function handleFile() {
  readData(showData);
}
```

My purpose is execute function showData() only when function readData() has finished. Using all I learned about callback with the code above, but console give `undefined` for first button click. It display correct data after second click. 
 Why was that happen ?

Comment: How did it not work? What happened and what was expected?

Comment: `get data from api/textbox..` if any of this is `async` your callback is going to trigger before it's ready.

Comment: Show us the actual code, not some pseudo comments. That's exactly the section where your problem lies.

Comment: @Bergi I just edited my questions. My stupid bad, sorry guys

Comment: @huudunghcmus Thanks. Yes, you need to move the `callback(data);` *inside* the onload handler

Comment: Thanks you so much. That solved my problem <3